# isdigit is not working correctly

Tags: c++, string, debugging

I am trying to test if a string contains an integer by iterating through the entire string and outputting the integer. My method involves converting the string to c-string , `atoi` the c-string and then testing if its an integer using `isdigit` function. For some unknown reason, `isdigit` function is returning false though it encounters a integer.

I need help resolving this issue

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string p = "[ab, e2cd]";

    for (int k = 0; k < p.length(); k++)
    {
        if (isdigit(atoi(p.substr(k,1).c_str())) == true) //testing done here
        {
            cout << atoi(p.substr(k, 1).c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass a character instead.

Comment: use `if (isdigit(*(p.substr(k,1).c_str())) == true) //testing done here` for a quick and dirty change

Answer (score 3):

[`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) takes an `int` with the value of a single character in your locale. It is OK to pass it an `unsigned char` cast from a `char`, and let the conversion to `int` do its thing. Since `string` contains `chars`, you can use it's elements like this:

```
if ( static_cast<unsigned char>(isdigit(p[k])) ) { ....
```

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` converts a cstring to a number. If the string is invalid, you wont know, because `atoi` returns 0, which could also be the number in the string.

`isdigit` Should be passed a character as an int and returns `false` if it is not a digit character. So you are comparing apple with oranges.

Just iterate over the string and pass each character to `isdigit()` and if this works, then you can use `atoi` to convert it.

One pitfall can be though, that the string contains `+` or `-` as part of the number, and `isdigit()` does not return `true` in this case. There may be other characters as well being part of a valid number, but for simple integer values, this should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `isdigit` is fairly bizarre, for historical reasons.

It takes a character value, and tells you whether it's a decimal digit (one of `'0'`, `'1'`, ... `'9'`) -- which means that applying it to the result of `atoi()` rarely makes sense.

But the character value is represented not as a `char`, but as an `int` whose value is in the range of `unsigned char`. Any other argument value (other than `EOF`, which is typically `-1`) causes undefined behavior. So if you want to test a `char` value, you should cast it to `unsigned char`; if plain `char` is signed, omitting the cast risks undefined behavior.

And the result isn't a `bool`. It's an `int` whose value is 0 for a non-digit, and any arbitrary non-zero value for a digit. Do not compare the result for equality to `true`. For that matter, don't compare *any* value that represents a condition for equality or inequality to `false` or `true`; it's already a condition, so just use it directly.

If `c` is a `char`, replace

```
if (isdigit(c) == true)
```

by

```
if (isdigit((unsigned char)c))
```

or

```
if (isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)))
```