# separate numeric char from user input and print

Tags: c

So I'm trying to read user input and print the numerical chars from the input, line by line. This is what I've got so far:

```
printf("Type characters in a line, with no spaces: \n\n");

scanf(" %c", &inp);

int check(char num, char oth, char inp, char c, int inum)
{
    if(c==0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    {
        printf("%c", &c);
    }
}
```

I'm a complete beginner and honestly am completely lost, I would appreciate some help or just for someone to point me in the right direction. Also I can't use strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In most encodings the characters that represent the digits are placed in ascending order starting with `'0'`, so you could simply check whether `c` is in range `['0', '1', ... '8', '9']` including both the beginning and the end.

```
int check(char num, char oth, char inp, char c, int inum)
{
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        printf("%c", c);
}
```

If you'd like to print the chars *line by line*, you should print a newline character (`'\n'`) as well: `printf("%c\n", c);`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the C Standard **mandates** that the characters `'0'` through `'9'` be positive and consecutive. *C11 5.2.1 Character sets: In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous*

Answer (score 1):

C language has a function, [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) (defined in [ctype.h](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm)), that does this verification for you:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
int check(char num, char oth, char inp, char c, int inum){
    if(isdigit((unsigned char)c)){
        printf("%c", &c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `isdigit((unsigned char)c)` as `char` can be signed by default and `isdigit()` is not defined for negative values different from `EOF`.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks, this answer explains it better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19900676/6196010